# How to access elements inside of a shadow DOM to use with synthetic scripted browser test(New Relic) with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom, newrelic

I am trying to grab and click on a button with New Relic's synthetic scripted browser test utility but the element I'm trying to find is under a `#shadow-root` in the DOM.  Node script looks like:

```
$browser.get('https://www.null.com').then(() => {
    return $browser.waitForAndFindElement($driver.By.className('btn'), 10000).click();
}):
```

But it errors out with:

> Check failed with task timed out. Error: task timed-out waiting for
> element to be located using:By(css selector, .btn)

I'm asking to see if there is a work around for grabbing elements in the shadow DOM to be able to use with the selenium webdriver.

Comment: I have also increased the wait time to 60 secs and have received the same results.

Comment: Did you check https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/synthetics/synthetic-monitoring/scripting-monitors/synthetic-scripted-browser-reference-monitor-versions-chrome-100/#shadow ?